# Weird behaviour when updating matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm displaying the top three players in a bar chart sorted from high to low scores. Depending on the score I want the bar chart to be updated. When a player yields a higher score than another these should change places. For updating the bar chart I use `remove()` and redraw the content of the bar chart by setting the new `top_scores` and `top_players` and pass them to the bar chart. But I encountered a very strange behaviour. While the xtick labels are updated properly in the chart, the bar heights are not. In my example 'Player A' is on the third position. If his score is increased his position will switch if his score is higher than the others. But only the original bar (in this case the third) is increased by its height even Player A being on the first place for example. I don't understand this behaviour, because I'm passing a completely new list to the bar chart. Has someone an idea why this happens?

Below is the code I'm working with. To increase the scores of a player I added a corresponding button.

P.S. If anyone could also tell me how I can update the `bar_labels` properly (in value and height) I would be thankful, because I couldn't find out how to update these.

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

players = ["Player A", "Player B", "Player C"]  # In the real code I have many more players
scores = [4, 7, 5]


def get_values():
    global top_scores
    global top_players
    top_scores = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[:3]  # Sorts the scores from highest to lowest and saves the highest three

    # Determines the indices of the best three scores in right order from the original list
    indices_list = sorted(range(len(scores)), key=lambda i: scores[i], reverse=True)[:3]

    top_players = []  # Get the names of the corresponding scores
    for j in range(0, len(indices_list)):
        top_players.append(players[indices_list[j]])

    print(top_scores)
    print(top_players)


def add_score(player):  # Player A = 0; Player B = 1; Player C = 2
    scores[player] += 1


def update():
    global bar_container
    bar_container.remove()
    bar_container = ax.bar(top_players, top_scores, color="#FF7F0E")
    ax.set_ylim(0, int(top_scores[0]) * 1.1)  # To adjust the y axis
    ax.set_xticks([0, 1, 2])
    ax.set_xticklabels(top_players)
    plt.draw()

get_values()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Plot the top three players with their corresponding scores
bar_container = ax.bar(top_players, top_scores, color="#FF7F0E")
ax.set_ylabel("Score")

# Displays the score on each bar
for label in ax.bar_label(bar_container):
    label.set_fontsize(8)

root = tk.Tk()
buttonA = tk.Button(root, text="Player A", command=lambda: [add_score(0), get_values(), update()])
buttonB = tk.Button(root, text="Player B", command=lambda: [add_score(1), get_values(), update()])
buttonC = tk.Button(root, text="Player C", command=lambda: [add_score(2), get_values(), update()])

chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
chart1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
buttonA.grid(row=1, column=0)
buttonB.grid(row=1, column=1)
buttonC.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please share a simplified version of your code that displays the same issue, i.e. a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JohnCollins I am looking for a matplotlib related solution only.